# How to convert a Zero curve to a Discount Curve

Tags: quantlib

I have created a `Zero-Curve` as below -

```
from QuantLib import *
spot_dates = [Date(1, 1, 2015), Date(1, 6, 2015), Date(1, 12, 2015), Date(1, 4, 2016), Date(1, 8, 2016)]
spot_rates = [0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08]
us_calendar = UnitedStates()
zero_curve = ZeroCurve(spot_dates, spot_rates, Actual365Fixed(), us_calendar, Linear(), Compounded, Annual)
```

Now I wish to transform this `zero_curve` to a `discount-curve`.

Does `QuantLib` offer any direct function to achieve the same.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ZeroCurve function.  Is it linearly interpolating between the spot rates you have?  Are the spot rates zero rates?

Comment: FinancePy can do this. I have made a notebook. It's beta but try it out if you are interested. https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/STACK_EXCHANGE_ConvertZeroCurveToDiscountCurve.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can build the curve in different ways (from spot rates, from discount factors, by bootstrapping instruments and by fitting instruments), once the curve instance is successfully built, as Luigi said, the discount method will give you the discount factors for dates or year fractions.

Example using you code:

```
dfs = [zero_curve.discount(dt) for dt, rate in zero_curve.nodes()]
print(dfs)
```

[1.0, 0.9918411458168641, 0.9647467581357048, 0.9297902787888683, 0.8852611853613657]

To specify the interpolation method you want for points that are not curve nodes, you can use different alternatives of ZeroCurve and Piecewise classes  (LogLinearZeroCurve, CubicZeroCurve, PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount, PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount, PiecewiseLinearZero, etc)

Answer (score 4):

Your curve can already be used as a discount curve.  Its `discount` method will do the conversion internally.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question as it is not Quantlib-related. I would just like to mention that I have just released a pure python finance library that does this called FinancePy. You can find it at https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy. It covers this functionality and gives you the ability to drop down into the underlying code.

You can install it using pip.

A set of example notebooks are provided at https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy-Examples.

Documentation can be found here.

https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy-Examples/blob/master/FinancePyManualV_0.180.pdf

It's a beta version so not guaranteed to be bug-free but I would be happy to get comments and feedback.